# compare data sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have code php like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT phone FROM user where phone LIKE 'hjkhkjh');


// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Account wasnt created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else  {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Account was created.";
```

I want to compare phone number in database , but when i run this code , this code show "account wasnt created" whereas I have data phone number 'hjkhkjh' in my table , any solution for my code, thanks

Comment: switch the $response["message"]'s to it's correct location

Comment: $result is evaluated to true when the query has been performed and you interpret that as the account was NOT created? Seems like a logic fail to me. Plus it's a select and NOT an insert.

Comment: He probably wants to check wether the insert has been successful or not. I think. Stil not the easiest way though...

Comment: You're also using a LIKE without adding any wildcards to your variable. You might as well just use `=` in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're writing "Account wasnt created" when the if-construct resolves to true.
Try it like this

```
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Account was created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else  {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Account wasnt created.";
```

Comment: I am sorry , I wanna ask , so how code if we want to select query not insert?? because code $result = mysql_query("SELECT phone FROM user where phone LIKE 'hjkhkjh'); its for insert right?

Comment: You'll have to reverse the if. 
$result resolves to true if there was a record, eg the query was successful.

Answer (score 1):

[www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) says:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

since your query doesn't produce error, return is resource, which passes `if ($result) {`
(regardless if there is actually entry in the db table which has phone LIKE 'hjkhkjh' or not)

Comment: actually I want ask is how to check and compare data in php . If i have data ' phone = 'hjkhkjh' i want show that account was created. but if data phone 'hjkhkjh' not found in database. i want show that account wasnt created .

Answer (score 1):

I found solution , i change my code like this 
$result =mysql_query("SELECT phone from user where phone ='hjkhkjh'");

```
// check if row inserted or not
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Account was created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else  {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Account wasnt created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

thanks all :D